# WebStorm project template

Tags: sencha-touch-2, webstorm

Is there a way to have our own project template. For example I would like to use it with sencha touch2  and create automatically the mvc folders structure for each new project created.
Any experience or help will be welcomed.

Comment: Unfortunately not -- this feature is still pending (despite the fact that lots of people would love to have it). Right now you have to do this manually (e.g. create a template folder structure with all the files somewhere on your computer and then copy all files into new project).

Comment: Ok thanks, It's really necessary to get such a feature on a modern IDE

Comment: The actual ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60187

Answer (score 0):

I have never personally used, but may be you found it useful [Efficient usage of WebStorm IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462285/efficient-usage-of-webstorm-ide/5900800#5900800)

Cheers, Oleg