# How to open/debug current file using built-in Web server in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

Is there a way to create a run configuration that will open the **file that is being edited** in the browser using the WebStorm built-in web server (`http://localhost:63342/`) and start the debugging?

reference: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/03/built-in-server-in-webstorm-6/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a run configuration, but a default **In place** deployment:

[image: server]

Note that the server configuration name (**LOCAL**) is in **bold** which means that it's the default (can be set from the right click menu or [an icon](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/1804/20130430054116.png)).

Configure **Mappings** like this:

[image: mappings]

where **project** is the name of your project.

Now you can use `View` | `Preview file in` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and enable `Live Edit` if needed.

---

Note that it's useful for the preview and will not start JavaScript debugging. To debug the scripts on a page right click in the file and use the **Debug** action in the `Run` or file context menu, or the corresponding keyboard shortcut:

[image: Debug]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It’s good to know that I can use deployments to view the current file but I really need a solution that attaches the debugger too. Using the the Debug action in the Run menu loads the file using `file://`; not using the local web server which is what I need.

Comment: With the correct deployment configuration **Debug** action will open it on the web server via `http://`. I've double checked it with the sample project before writing the answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I didn't test it right yesterday. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI - you can change the port for the built-in server by going to Settings->Debugger->JavaScript - the first option is the port setting.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that does not require setup for every project is to create an external tool that will load your browser of preference with the proper path. Here is an example on how to set that up using chrome:

[image: external tools setup]

Program:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Parameters (don't forget the quotes in case file names have spaces in them):

```
"http://localhost:63342/$ProjectName$/$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$"
```

Working Directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Once you set this up it will work on any project. Make sure to tweak the program path and working directory to the path where your chrome browser is installed.